# Wait for toast to disappear in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, toastr, angular-toastr

**Summary**

How do I wait for all toasts to disappear when using Protractor for testing an AngularJS webapp?

**More details**

I have an AngularJS app, that I am testing using Protractor. I am using angular-toastr to show notifications when things happen in the application.

At one point in the tests, I am unable to click a button because a toast is currently blocking the button. The error I get is:

`Element is not clickable at point (898, 712). Other element would receive the click: <div id="toast-container" {...}`

So I want to wait for the toast to disappear before continuing. Since angular-toastr does not use `$timeout`, I can not do this with `browser.waitForAngular();`

So how should I do it?

**What am I NOT trying to do?**

I am not trying to test the contents of the toast. Right now, I don't care about the toast at all, I just want to click the button that the toast is obscuring.

Comment: I would use, ExpectedConditions: invisibilityOf / stalenessOf to verify if the toast no longer exists in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the element being not present (or alternatively not displayed):

```
browser.wait(function () {
    return $('#toast-container').isPresent().then(function (toastPresent) {
        return !toastPresent;
    });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a starting point in this blog post: http://docsplendid.com/archives/209

I tweaked it a bit to work with toastr, and this is where it ended up:

```
var hasClicked = false;

browser.wait(function() {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

    var elements = element.all(by.className('toast'));
    var count = elements.count().then(function (result) {
        // If there are toasts active, click them to hide them faster.
        if (result > 0 && !hasClicked) {
            elements.click();
            hasClicked = true;
        }
        deferred.fulfill(result === 0);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your quest but you can click on the Toastr message to make it disappear before attempting to click the button being obscured.

```
element(by.css(".toast-message")).click()
```